# AutoHotkey: Why are assignment, InsertAt, length, and MaxIndex, not working on an array generated by RegExMatch()?

Tags: arrays, autohotkey

In AutoHotkey, [RegExMatch()](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExMatch.htm) in mode 3 (match object) puts the matched strings in an [array](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Objects.htm#Usage_Simple_Arrays). I can get the matches using `array[index]`, and I can get the number of matches using [.count()](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/objects/Object.htm#Count). But I have the following problems:

- When I try to change the value of an element of the array with `:=`, the value does not change.
- When I try to insert an element using [.InsertAt](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/objects/Object.htm#InsertAt), nothing is inserted.
- When I try to get the size of the array using [.length()](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/objects/Object.htm#Length) or [.MaxIndex()](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/objects/Object.htm#MinMaxIndex), I get nothing.

This behavior is demonstrated by the following script:

```
; "TestScript.ahk"

; Use a regular expression to read data from a string, then test the behavior of the resulting array.

#NoEnv
#Warn

^+z::                           ; Hotkey for this script: Ctrl-shift-Z
sDataString := "A1B2C3"
nFoundPosn := RegExMatch(sDataString, "O)A(\d)B(\d)C(\d)", asData)
asData[2] := "4"
asData.InsertAt(3, "5")
MsgBox % "I expect the following to produce:`n"
        . "{1, 4, 5, 3}`n"
        . ">4<, >4<, >4<`n"
        . "`n"
        . "but instead I get:`n"
        . "{" . asData[1] . ", " . asData[2] . ", " . asData[3] . ", " . asData[4] . "}`n"
        . ">" . asData.count() . "<, >" . asData.length() . "<, >" . asData.MaxIndex() . "<"
return
```

which produces the following output:

[image]

Obviously, there's something I don't understand about the array that's being produced and how to work with it. The fact that assignment and insertion don't work suggests to me that the array variable is a pointer, but I don't see anything about that in the documentation linked above, so if it is a pointer, I don't know how to access the object it's pointing to. What am I doing wrong, or what do I misunderstand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What an interesting thing you've come across! I thought that you surely had made an error, but I was wrong. It appears that the only usable properties are those [listed in the help documentation for that mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExMatch.htm#MatchObject). Annoyingly, it cannot be treated as a standard object; you can't even clone it to do useful work with it. As highly-esteemed AHK forum user **jeeswg** found ([here](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=40679)), the only option is to loop through the match object and build an array from it, as demonstrated below.

```
^+z::
asDataNew := []
sDataString := "A1B2C3"
nFoundPosn := RegExMatch(sDataString, "O)A(\d)B(\d)C(\d)", asData)

Loop , % asData.count()
    asDataNew[A_Index] := asData[A_Index]

asDataNew[2] := "4"
asDataNew.InsertAt(3, "5")
MsgBox % "I expect the following to produce:`n"
        . "{1, 4, 5, 3}`n"
        . ">4<, >4<, >4<`n"
        . "`n"
        . "but instead I get:`n"
        . "{" . asData.1 . ", " . asData[2] . ", " . asData[3] . ", " . asData[4] . "}`n"
        . ">" . asData.count() . "<, >" . asData.length() . "<, >" . asData.MaxIndex() . "<`n"
        . "`n"
        . "With hard copy I get:`n"
        . "{" . asDataNew.1 . ", " . asDataNew[2] . ", " . asDataNew[3] . ", " . asDataNew[4] . "}`n"
        . ">" . asDataNew.count() . "<, >" . asDataNew.length() . "<, >" . asDataNew.MaxIndex() . "<"
return
```

Comment: Thank you. That post by jeeswg also suggests a reason that it might be that way: "optimization ... with large strings in mind, where having things read-only is advantageous." That makes sense because RegEx is indeed often used (including by me) on very large strings, so that makes me feel better about having to write a little loop to convert the results to something I can manipulate. As you've shown, the code for the loop is trivial.

Comment: @NewSites Ah, I see, thanks for the insight. Still, it would be nice to be able to clone it at least.